# how to access psql database in mocha js test of javascript?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, psql

I have  javascript code for client side and stores some data in server side in psql.I unit tested the script code using mocha js.While running, the test data is stored in postgres database. I need to remove the test data from database in mocha tests.I am new to it.Could you please help me??